# Usage of AN before a consonant

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I am a bit confused on when to use **a** or **an**. I understand "a" comes before a consonant, while "an" is followed by a vowel. But obviously an expression like `an significant part` is also true (reading an article by some native English-Speaking authors). Can some one explain how is here `significant` a use case for **an**?

Its an article here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288162668_Computational_music_theory. If you download the pdf, just at the beginning of **Introduction** in the second line.

Comment: "An significant part" is a mistake. Where exactly did you see this?  (can you provide a link?)

Comment: Its an article here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288162668_Computational_music_theory. If you download the pdf, just at the beginning of **Introduction** in the second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error. The error seems to be quite common, perhaps as people write "an important"  then edit to change "important" to "significant", but forget to change the article.  But this is speculation.  Nevertheless, it is an error. You shouldn't say (or write) "an significant".

The word "an" is based entirely on the vowel sound of the following word, hence "an urge, a uniform, a hat, an hour."